# What to set ANDROID_SDK ROOT to in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the error I am getting.

emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

Comment: You need to update your PATH variables in your operating system... Which is what?

Comment: The OS is Windows 8.1. What do I add in the PATH?

Answer (score 1):

You can view your system variables if you search for "environment variables" in the Start Menu. [See here for more information](http://www.itechtics.com/customize-windows-environment-variables/).

Then once you have that open, add a variable for `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. Android Studio should have done this all for you, but depending on where you have downloaded the [Android SDK tools](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html), you need to set the value for that variable to the path of the SDK folder, such as `C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\android-sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the Android SDK downloaded (most likely this is already done). Then figure out where it is saved and make a note of that directory it is downloaded to. Finally go to the "Project Structure" on the File menu and choose the "SDK Location" bar and set the the Android SDK Location field to where the SDK is downloaded.